# Set a variable inside the function, but to be used outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not goot at javascript but i was trying to edit this userscript in order to produce different values everytime a key is pressed.

The original code has the var scanFreq and isDoneLoadingFreq set to an exact value, like 400. I wanted it to be random, that's why the Math function. But it only triggers once, so the code will always be repeating the switch(whichMove) case 1:, case2: etc.

I tried to generate the random numbers insite each case, but then the values won't come outside.

Edit: the isDoneLoadingFreq is beeing loaded in the setInterval(function(), right?
My goal is go make that value random every time a key is pressed :|

Edit2: (Code edited according to wwv)
This first function is triggered once it finds a pokémon. But It's old code, and the objective is that after the alert is closed, the code should not run more. What do I need to change? (Check the pastebin in the end of the post for more code, if you think there's something missing)

Edit3: Edited the function in order to stop the loop after an alert pops, but it's still happening

```
function found(thing){
        if($('#pkmnappear').first().html().toLowerCase().indexOf(thing.toLowerCase()) > -1){
            alert("Found Something");
            finderOn = true;
            clearInterval(a);
            if(autoWalkFind){
                clearInterval(b);
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }        
function setFinder(){
            finderOn = true;

            if(autoWalkFind) {
                var b;

                var checkLoading = function(){
                    var isLoading = $("#pkmnappear").text().indexOf("Please wait") > -1;
                    if(!isLoading){
                        switch(whichMove){
                            case 1:
                                fireKey(document,37);
                                whichMove = 2;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fireKey(document,38);
                                whichMove = 3;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                fireKey(document,39);
                                whichMove = 4;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                fireKey(document,40);
                                whichMove = 1;
                                break;
                        }
                        moveTimes=0;
                    }else{
                        moveTimes++;
                         // Not done loading. check again after a random delay
                        b = setTimeout(checkLoading, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 400);
                    }
                    if(moveTimes >= 100)
                        location.reload(true);

                    // call setTimeout again with a new delay
                    b = setTimeout(checkLoading, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 400);
                }

                // call setTimeout with the first delay
                b = setTimeout(checkLoading, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 400);
            }

            var a;
            var scan = function(){
                var stopChecking = false;

                if(findPokemon)
                    for (var i = 0; i < pokemonToFind.length; i++)
                        stopChecking = stopChecking || found(pokemonToFind[i]);

                if(findLevels)
                    for (var i = 0; i < levelsToFind.length; i++)
                        stopChecking = stopChecking || found("Level: " + levelsToFind[i] + " ");

                if(findLevelsAndUp)
                    for(var l = levelsAndUpToFind; l<101;l++)
                        if (found("Level: " + l + " ")) {
                            stopChecking = true;
                            break;
                        }

                // Nothing found. check again after a random delay
                if(!stopChecking) {
                    a = setTimeout(scan, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 120);
                }
            }

            // call setTimeout with the first delay
            a = setTimeout(scan, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 120);

       }

        setFinder();
```

This is a link to the whole code I was using, just in case it's necessary: https://pastebin.com/Q0GudL5c

Comment: The first thing I would do is wrap all your control blocks (`if/then` brances, body of `for` loops in curly braces because, right now, your code is just begging to be infested with bugs.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. Which variables do you want accessible outside the function? And the answer is, if you declare a variable inside a function, the only way to get it out is to `return` it from the function. Try making your question a little more detailed and then someone can help more.

Comment: Scott, I usually do that but this code wasn't mine and it's working, so I didn't change it.

Arnav, I edited the post, maybe it's more clear now? :|

Answer (score 0):

`scanFreq` and `isDoneLoadingFreq` are defined only when `setFinder` is called. In order to make it dynamic you have to define it as a function like this for example

```
var scanFreq = (function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 110; });
var math2 = (function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 400; });
var isDoneLoadingFreq = math2;
```

And then in `setInterval` you call `setInterval(your_func, scanFreq())`

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will repeatedly execute the code at a set frequency. I'm not aware of any way to change that frequency, so changing those variables will have no effect.

However, `setTimeout`, will execute the code only once. Then if you add `setTimeout` calls at the end of the function, you can randomly generate a new delay each time.

To do that though you'll have to store the functions in variables. So your code will end up looking something like this:

```
    function setFinder(){
        finderOn = true;

        if(autoWalkFind) {
            var b;

            var checkLoading = function(){
                var isLoading = $("#pkmnappear").text().indexOf("Please wait") > -1;
            if(!isLoading){
                // ...
            }else{
                moveTimes++;

                    // Not done loading. check again after a random delay
                    b = setTimeout(checkLoading, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 400);
            }
                // ...
                // ...
            }


        }

        var a;
        var scan = function(){
            var stopChecking = false;

            if(findPokemon)
                for (var i = 0; i < pokemonToFind.length; i++)
                    stopChecking = stopChecking || found(pokemonToFind[i]);

            if(findLevels)
                for (var i = 0; i < levelsToFind.length; i++)
                    stopChecking = stopChecking || found("Level: " + levelsToFind[i] + " ");

            if(findLevelsAndUp)
                for(var l = levelsAndUpToFind; l<101;l++)
                    if (found("Level: " + l + " ")) {
                        stopChecking = true;
                        break;
                    }

            // Nothing found. check again after a random delay
            if(!stopChecking) {
                a = setTimeout(scan, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 400);
            }
        }

        // call setTimeout with the first delay
        a = setTimeout(scan, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 400);

   }
```

Comment: Yes it's close to what I want,but when it finds a pokémon it pops an alert, and after closing the alert the script continues instead of stopping. I edited the post with the code I think it's responsible for that, what do I need to change?

Comment: I edited it better now, I hope it's understandable :)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. In that case, you can add a condition around `setTimeout` so that it doesn't get called if `found` returns true. I'll make an edit. I'll also add the move b's setTimeout inside the else block of `if(!isLoading)`

Comment: Hm It still doesn't stop for some reason. I edited my post again with the updated code, did I do anything wrong? And btw, sometimes the code gets crazy for some reason, it presses the keys with no delay at all